# Phone reboots when image file is tried to open from application 2nd time in 23 sdk version?

Tags: android, file, uri, android-snackbar

I Just created an application which takes the screenshot of the page when a button is clicked and after saving to folder the snackbar with open icon shows. When i press the open, the image is opened but not in the gallery, as if it is opened from a file manager! But till then its okay! Again if i press button this time the phone just restarts. weird!! It does not have any issue upto lollypop!! But this happens only in Android Marshmallow!!

my Code to save screenshot and open the image is:

```
 private void temp(){
        RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.printLayout);// which includes your view or buttons?
        parent.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(parent.getDrawingCache());
        parent.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        try {
            final File f = savebitmap(bitmap);
            Log.e("File Loc",f.toString());
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "Image saved successfully in mobeeload folder", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("OPEN", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + f.getAbsolutePath());
                            intent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
            snackbar.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static File savebitmap(Bitmap bmp) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, bytes);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "MobeeLoad/testimage.jpg");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
        return f;
    }
```

**---------UPDATE------------**

I found that the image is opened in same application (my App) and not in any gallery app in my phone!!

Comment: Weird, Is there any error in log?

Comment: I could not take it! The phone freezes and goes to reboot!! But when i come back to previous activity and again click save then again it opens the image!! It happens when trying to save the image back to back

Comment: Must be a memory issues then, try to recycle your `bitmap` after writing into a disk.

Comment: How could i do that!! I am new to android plz

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on your comment -

> It happens when trying to save the image back to back

Must be a memory problem, Try to `recycle` your bitmap after writing it into a disk. Here is how you can do that -

```
public static File savebitmap(Bitmap bmp) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, bytes);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "MobeeLoad/testimage.jpg");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
        bmp.recycle();
        return f;
    }
```

Comment: Let me check this!!

Comment: No still the phone restarts!!